# AIR - Making use of air.swf file in an internal network

Tags: apache-flex, security, air

Hello StackOverflow community,

The air.swf file referenced here:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html

used to launch AIR applications from Flex applications requires the use of an air.swf file located here:
http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf

We have tried to download this SWF and use it in our internal network, but it is not working, we depend on using the one located in the Adobe site.

Is there anyway to use this air.swf file without having to access the Adobe site?

Thanks!
Mauricio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this swf will not work if it's not loaded from adobe.com domain.

Comment: It looks this way, but I can't believe that Adobe would not create something that enterprise users can use in an internal network

Answer (score 0):

You can download the air.swf from the Adobe website (which the docs say you are free to do) and load it locally. Then the first call correctly gives the status of the AIR installation - "installed" or "available". However, if AIR is installed, the next call to getApplicationVersion always fails with "null" no matter the AIR app is installed or not. If I run the Adobe hosted version of air.swf everything works fine.
I am trying with AIR 2.0 and Actionscript 3.0.
i know this is rather a partial answer, but if I figure out more I will edit it!